# onTaskCahanged inside a while loop

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow that creates a new task at the time of creation of a new item in a given list. This new task is assigned to a user when created. Then, this task can either be reassigned or completed. If the task is completed, the workflow ends. If the task is reassigned, the task should be completed, another task should be created assigned to another user, and the workflow continues.

I have the issue that when the second task is created(first task is reassigned) the workflow ends and the onTaskChanged of the second task is never hit.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error I had. I was trying to store an instance of SPFieldUserValue in a class variable of the workflow class. SPFieldUserValue is not serializable and was trhowing an error. This caused that the workflow terminated, so it just halted.